# Retrieving dict value via hardcoded key, works. Retrieving via computed key doesn't. Why?

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, dictionary, format

I'm generating a common list of IDs by comparing two sets of IDs (the ID sets are from a dictionary, `{ID: XML "RECORD" element}`). Once I have the common list, I want to iterate over it and retrieve the value corresponding to the ID from a dictionary (which I'll write to disc).

When I compute the common ID list using my diff_comm_checker function, I'm unable to retrieve the dict value the ID corresponds to. It doesn't however fail with a KeyError. I can also print the ID out.

When I hard code the ID in as the common_id value, I can retrieve the dict value.

I.e.

```
common_ids = diff_comm_checker( list_1, list_2, "text")
# does nothing - no failures

common_ids = ['0603599998140032MB']
#gives me:

0603599998140032MB {'R': '0603599998140032MB'} <Element 'RECORD' at 0x04ACE788>
0603599998140032MB {'R': '0603599998140032MB'} <Element 'RECORD' at 0x04ACE3E0>
```

So I suspected there was some difference between the strings. I checked both the function output and compared it against the hard-coded values using:

```
print [(_id, type(_id), repr(_id)) for _id in common_ids][0]
```

I get exactly the same for both:

```
>>> ('0603599998140032MB', <type 'str'>, "'0603599998140032MB'")
```

I have also followed the advice of another question and used difflib.ndiff:

```
common_ids1 = diff_comm_checker( [x.keys() for x in to_write[0]][0], [x.keys() for x in to_write[1]][0], "text")
common_ids = ['0603599998140032MB']
print "\n".join(difflib.ndiff(common_ids1, common_ids))
>>>  0603599998140032MB
```

So again, doesn't appear that there's any difference between the two.

Here's a full, working example of the code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from itertools import chain, islice

def diff_comm_checker(list_1, list_2, text):
    """Checks 2 lists. If no difference, pass. Else return common set between two lists"""

    symm_diff = set(list_1).symmetric_difference(list_2)
    if not symm_diff:
        pass
    else:
        mismatches_in1_not2 = set(list_1).difference( set(list_2) )
        mismatches_in2_not1 = set(list_2).difference( set(list_1) )

        if mismatches_in1_not2:
            mismatch_logger(
                mismatches_in1_not2,"{}\n1: {}\n2: {}".format(text, list_1, list_2), 1, 2)
        if mismatches_in2_not1:
            mismatch_logger(
                mismatches_in2_not1,"{}\n2: {}\n1: {}".format(text, list_1, list_2), 2, 1)

    set_common = set(list_1).intersection( set(list_2) )
    if set_common:
        return sorted(set_common)
    else:
        return "no common set: {}\n".format(text)


def chunks(iterable, size=10):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for first in iterator:
        yield chain([first], islice(iterator, size - 1))

def get_elements_iteratively(file):
    """Create unique ID out of image number and case number, return it along with corresponding xml element"""

    tag = "RECORD"

    tree = ET.iterparse(StringIO(file), events=("start","end"))
    context = iter(tree)
    _, root = next(context)

    for event, record in context:
        if event == 'end' and record.tag == tag:
            xml_element_2 = ''
            xml_element_1 = ''
            for child in record.getchildren():
                if child.tag == "IMAGE_NUMBER":
                    xml_element_1 = child.text
                if child.tag == "CASE_NUM":
                    xml_element_2 = child.text
            r_id = "{}{}".format(xml_element_1, xml_element_2)
            record.set("R", r_id)
            yield (r_id, record)
            root.clear()

def get_chunks(file, chunk_size):
    """Breaks XML into chunks, yields dict containing unique IDs and corresponding xml elements"""

    iterable = get_elements_iteratively(file)

    for chunk in chunks(iterable, chunk_size):
        ids_records = {}
        for k in chunk:
            ids_records[k[0]]=k[1]

        yield ids_records

def create_new_xml(xml_list):

    chunk = 5000

    chunk_rec_ids_1 = get_chunks(xml_list[0], chunk)
    chunk_rec_ids_2 = get_chunks(xml_list[1], chunk)
    to_write = [chunk_rec_ids_1, chunk_rec_ids_2]

    ######################################################################################
    ### WHAT'S GOING HERE ??? WHAT'S THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE OUTPUTS OF THESE TWO ? ###

    common_ids = diff_comm_checker( [x.keys() for x in to_write[0]][0], [x.keys() for x in to_write[1]][0], "create_new_xml - large - common_ids")
    #common_ids = ['0603599998140032MB']

    ######################################################################################

    for _id in common_ids:
        print _id
        for gen_obj in to_write:
            for kv_pair in gen_obj:
                if kv_pair[_id]:
                    print _id, kv_pair[_id].attrib, kv_pair[_id]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    xml_1 = """<?xml version="1.0"?><RECORDSET><RECORD><CASE_NUM>140032MB</CASE_NUM><IMAGE_NUMBER>0603599998</IMAGE_NUMBER></RECORD></RECORDSET>"""
    xml_2 = """<?xml version="1.0"?><RECORDSET><RECORD><CASE_NUM>140032MB</CASE_NUM><IMAGE_NUMBER>0603599998</IMAGE_NUMBER></RECORD></RECORDSET>"""
    create_new_xml([xml_1, xml_2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the type or value of common_ids returned from diff_comm_checker. The problem is that the function diff_comm_checker or in constructing the arguments to the function that destroys the values of to_write

If you try this you will see what I mean

```
common_ids = ['0603599998140032MB']
diff_comm_checker( [x.keys() for x in to_write[0]][0], [x.keys() for x in to_write[1]][0], "create_new_xml - large - common_ids")
```

This will give the erroneous behavior without using the return value from diff_comm_checker()

This is because to_write is a generator and the call to diff_comm_checker exhausts that generator. The generator is then finished/empty when used in the if-statement in the loop. You can create a list from a generator by using *list*:

```
chunk_rec_ids_1 = list(get_chunks(xml_list[0], chunk))
chunk_rec_ids_2 = list(get_chunks(xml_list[1], chunk))
```

But this may have other implications (memory usage...)

Also, what is the intention of this construct in diff_comm_checker?

```
    if not symm_diff:
       pass
```

In my opinion nothing will happen regardless if symm_diff is *None* or not.

Comment: I excluded some of the code as I thought it irrelevant - have now put that back. If there was no differences between the sets, I wanted to skip the `difference()` functions.

Comment: So is there some way to utilise the `diff_comm_checker` func without destroying the values of `to_write`? I am going to try returning a list alongside the `ids_records` dict, but if there's a better way, please let me know

Comment: to_write is a generator, not a list. Your call to diff_com_checker exhausts the items in the generator. When you later try to use the generator again it is empty

Comment: Thanks - I understand the issue now. I have tried generating a list as you suggested but there are indeed memory issues during construction of the list. I will look for another way to do this. Will award the bounty in 2 hours when I'm allowed to.